# Problem deploying "express-gateway" to Google Kubernetes Engine with Ingress service type

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm deploying a microservices nodejs express application to GKE, I successfully deployed the services (one as Ingress service with static IP @ and one as NodePort service which will not be exposed to Internet).

Now I'm trying to deploy the api gateway which is an express-gateway application, I deployed it in first time as a LoadBalancer service and it's working , here is my service code :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: express-gateway-balancer
spec:
  selector:
    app: express-gateway
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

[image: LoadBalancer Service]

Now I must transform the trafic to HTTPS to be able to call the API endpoints front my react frontend application which is running with HTTPS, so I did a research and the way is to expose the api gateway application as an Ingress not LoadBalancer.

So I did the changes (the same I did with the rest of my deployments)and created a static IP @ "gateway-ip" to expose it via Ingress :

Here is my service.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: express-gateway-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: express-gateway
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

My Ingress.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "gateway-ip"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: express-gateway-service
    servicePort: 80
```

Here is my deployment file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-gateway
  labels:
    app: express-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: express-gateway
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  express-gateway
          image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/apigatewayservice:v1
          ports:
            - name: gateway
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 9876
```

Here are screenshot of the error I got :

[image: Service error console]
[image: Service error browser]

Any solutions ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a default endpoint of all your scheduled pods? I mean "/" ? Ingress does the health check readiness prob inbuilt that checks if "/" is reachable or not. If not, it will declare it as unhealthy.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I need to implement it on Ingress side or express-gateway side ?

Comment: The backend pod which is exposed via NodePort needs to have an endpoint "/". You said you are using nodejs, so if you are using express or any other rest API library, then keep a default endpoint in your code - "/". This will be accessed by ingress to verify if the backend service is healthy or not. So you don't need to make this include at ingress side. In GCP it is very easy to track, if you click on unhealthy backend services, it will take you to there.